# Find the maximum of $A=\sin (x+y)+\cos(x-y)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

> Find the maximum of $A:$
>
> $$A=\sin (x+y)+\cos(x-y)$$

---

My Try :

$$A=\sin (x+y)+\cos(x-y)\\ =(\sin x\cos y+\cos x\sin y)+(\cos x \cos y +\sin x\sin y)$$

now what ?

Comment: with respect to what?

Comment: Why don't you try factoring the last formula a little more?

Answer (score 2):

Note that $A=(\sin x + \cos x) ( \sin y + \cos y)$.

Try to maximise/minimise the $\sin x + \cos x$ and $\sin y + \cos y$ 
separately.

Comment: Wow. I did not see that factorization. Also we can use the fact $\sin x+\cos x=\sqrt{2}\sin(x+\pi/4).$

Comment: @Bumblebee: Yes, that is how I would approach the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not specify the domain let me assume $x,y\in [0,\pi/2].$ Since $\cos$ function has the maximum at $0$ we can choose $x=y$ and since $\sin$ function has its maximum at $\pi/2$ again we can choose $x+y=\pi/2.$ Hence $$A_{\text{max}}=A(\pi/4,\pi/4)=2.$$ In fact we can find all maximums of $A$ using the periodicity.

Answer (score 1):

As $\sin(90^\circ+B)=\cos B,$

$$A=\sin(x+y)+\cos(x-y)=\sin(x+y)+\sin(90^\circ+x-y)$$

Using [Prosthaphaeresis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) Formula,

$$A=2\sin(45^\circ+x)\cos(45^\circ-y)$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

If we cancel the partial derivatives,

$$A'_x=\cos(x+y)-\sin(x-y)=0,\\A'_y=\cos(x+y)+\sin(x-y)=0$$

we immediately get

$$x+y=2k\pi\pm\frac\pi2,\\x-y=k\pi.$$